# Anything but subexpressions

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am trying to make a regex to identify relative  src paths using PHP. To do this my idea was to use a look ahead (?= then not ^ and a subexpression (http) but this doesn't work. It works for a single charater but the ^ doesn't work with a subexpression. Is there an && operator or something?

```
 <img.*?src=[\'\"]\(?=^(http))
```

I need it to take the entire http or else imgs with starting with h, t or p will be prejudiced against. Any suggestions? Is this task too big for regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead, which is `(?!...)` instead of `(?=...)`. For your example (I'd put the anchor at the start):

```
^(?!http)
```

Which reads: start of string, then something which is not "http".

**Edit**: since you updated with a fuller example:

```
<img [^>]*src=['"](?!http)([^'"]+)['"]

                          ^------^ - this capturing group captures the link
                                     which doesn't start with http
```

Of course, for proper parsing you should use DOM ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most useful answer, but it sounds as though you've reached the limit of applicabiliy for Regex in HTML parsing.

As per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) look at using a HTML DOM Parser. I haevn't used PHP DOM Parser's much, but I know in other languages, a DOM parser often makes HTML tasks a 30 second job, rather than an hour or more of weird exceptional case testing.

Comment: I tend to jump on the "Don't parse *ML with regex" bandwagon as well, but in this case, this question is really independent of HTML parsing.  It's actually a question of URL parsing.  Even if joel uses a proper parser to extract the URL, he still has the same basic problem.

Comment: @Frank Farmer - Yep you're right, although if you had a parser to grab the value of the SRC attribute, couldn't you just do a `StartsWith("http://")` equivalent in PHP